# How to group entities in cesium

Tags: javascript, cesiumjs

I want to group some 3D object in Cesium in order to switch their visibility by group
so I created an `EntityCollection` in order to group them and switch their visibility to on/off:

```
this.cylinders = new Cesium.EntityCollection()
```

I have a loop which adds several cylinders:

```
this.cylinders.add({
    name : g.name,
    position: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(coordinates[0], coordinates[1], 0),
    cylinder : {
        length : g.height,
        topRadius : g.distance,
        bottomRadius : g.distance,
        material : Cesium.Color.ORANGE.withAlpha(0.5),
        heightReference: Cesium.HeightReference.CLAMP_TO_GROUND,
    }
})
```

and I am adding this collection of cylinders to the viewer's entites

```
this.viewer.entities.add(this.cylinders)
```

unfortunately the cylinders which are added to the collection are not presented in the terrain

Comment: Try using a DataSource (or a CzmlDataSource) that has a `show` flag and contains an EntityCollection.

Comment: @emackey I am trying to add the entity to the a datasource but I am getting this error

`Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Property'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1930, 9): The expected type comes from property 'length' which is declared here on type 'CylinderGraphics'`